# Neural Network: Handwriting recognition - Use own images

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I've recently been following an excellent tutorial at http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html to create a neural network capable of recognising handwritten digits in Python, but I'm a bit confused as to how to use the trained network to recognise my own images.

I found this code on a similar SO thread to convert an image to the array I need:

```
data = np.vectorize(lambda x: 255 - x)(np.ndarray.flatten(scipy.ndimage.imread("test.png", flatten=True)))
```

I thought if I just put this through the feedforward function after the network has trained through 10 epochs

```
def feedforward(self,a):
    for b, w in zip(self.biases, self.weights):
        a = sigmoid(np.dot(w, a)+b)
    return a
```

then it would return the result - as I soon found it instead returned the array of Sigmoid Neurons and which ones fired, which I correlated to the output with the following code:

```
print("Prediction: " + str(unravel_index(np.argmax(data),data.shape)[1]))
```

This works for some images such as the following:
[image: Handwritten Digit]

But returns a value close to or just completely wrong for other images such as the following:

[image: Another Handwritten Digit]

I've done some searching and nobody else seems to have a precise answer to this problem or an answer with an example or explanation as to how to do it.

Am I not supposed to send the image through the feedforward method? It was the logical conclusion looking backwards through the code. And in which case, what do I send it through?

**Entire Code**

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import random

# Example - net = Network([2,3,1]) creates a network with 2 neurons in
# the first layer, 3 in the second (hidden) and 1 in the final layer.
class Network(object):

def __init__(self,sizes):
    self.num_layers = len(sizes)
    self.sizes = sizes
    self.biases = [np.random.randn(y, 1) for y in sizes[1:]] # Initializes
    # Biases and weights randomly.
    self.weights = [np.random.randn(y, x) # Stored as Numpy matrices.
                    for x, y in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])]
def feedforward(self,a):
    for b, w in zip(self.biases, self.weights):
        a = sigmoid(np.dot(w, a)+b)
    return a

def SGD(self, training_data, epochs, mini_batch_size, eta, test_data=None):
    # Train the network using mini batch stoachastic gradient
    # descent. The "training_data" is a list of tuples "(x,y)" representing
    # training inputs and desired outputs. The "eta" is the learning rate.

    if test_data: n_test = len(test_data)
    n = len(training_data)
    for j in xrange(epochs): # Shuffles training data and aplies SGD for
        # each mini_batch.
        random.shuffle(training_data)
        mini_batches = [
            training_data[k:k+mini_batch_size]
            for k in xrange(0, n, mini_batch_size)]
        for mini_batch in mini_batches:
            self.update_mini_batch(mini_batch, eta)
        if test_data:
            print "Epoch {0}: {1} / {2}".format(
                j, self.evaluate(test_data), n_test)
        else:
            print "Epoch {0} complete".format(j)
def update_mini_batch(self, mini_batch, eta):
    #Update the network's weights and biases by applying
    #gradient descent using backpropagation to a single mini batch.
    #The "mini_batch" is a list of tuples "(x, y)", and "eta"
    #is the learning rate.
    nabla_b = [np.zeros(b.shape) for b in self.biases]
    nabla_w = [np.zeros(w.shape) for w in self.weights]
    for x, y in mini_batch:
        delta_nabla_b, delta_nabla_w = self.backprop(x, y) # Invokes
        # backpropagation to compute gradient of the cost function.
        nabla_b = [nb+dnb for nb, dnb in zip(nabla_b, delta_nabla_b)]
        nabla_w = [nw+dnw for nw, dnw in zip(nabla_w, delta_nabla_w)]
    self.weights = [w-(eta/len(mini_batch))*nw 
                    for w, nw in zip(self.weights, nabla_w)]
    self.biases = [b-(eta/len(mini_batch))*nb 
                   for b, nb in zip(self.biases, nabla_b)]

def backprop(self, x, y):
    nabla_b = [np.zeros(b.shape) for b in self.biases]
    nabla_w = [np.zeros(w.shape) for w in self.weights]
    # feedforward
    activation = x
    activations = [x] # list to store all the activations, layer by layer
    zs = [] # list to store all the z vectors, layer by layer
    for b, w in zip(self.biases, self.weights):
        z = np.dot(w, activation)+b
        zs.append(z)
        activation = sigmoid(z)
        activations.append(activation)
    # backward pass
    delta = self.cost_derivative(activations[-1], y) * \
        sigmoid_prime(zs[-1])
    nabla_b[-1] = delta
    nabla_w[-1] = np.dot(delta, activations[-2].transpose())
    # Note that the variable l in the loop below is used a little
    # differently to the notation in Chapter 2 of the book.  Here,
    # l = 1 means the last layer of neurons, l = 2 is the
    # second-last layer, and so on.  It's a renumbering of the
    # scheme in the book, used here to take advantage of the fact
    # that Python can use negative indices in lists.
    for l in xrange(2, self.num_layers):
        z = zs[-l]
        sp = sigmoid_prime(z)
        delta = np.dot(self.weights[-l+1].transpose(), delta) * sp
        nabla_b[-l] = delta
        nabla_w[-l] = np.dot(delta, activations[-l-1].transpose())
    return (nabla_b, nabla_w)

def evaluate(self, test_data):
    test_results = [(np.argmax(self.feedforward(x)), y)
                    for (x, y) in test_data]
    return sum(int(x == y) for (x, y) in test_results)

def cost_derivative(self, output_activations, y):
    return (output_activations-y)

# Miscellaneous Functions
def sigmoid(z):
    return 1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-z)) # Sigmoid Function in Vector Form
def sigmoid_prime(z):
    #Derivative of the sigmoid function.
return sigmoid(z)*(1-sigmoid(z))
```

Comment: Yes you should it pass it to your NN. It is just the accuracy of your model is low so it can't recognize all numbers such as 6 correctly. For further diagnoisis of your particular problem, you have to report the accuracy of your model. For that you have to count the number of samples it mistakenly classifies / divided by the total number of samples and report it here

Comment: @TNM With that 6 image, after 10 epochs with 30 hidden neurons: `Epoch 9: 9437 / 10000` so  94.37% accuracy, and it prints `Prediction: 1`